# Generic Dataset without Database ask for log on information

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

I'm trying to push a generated dataset into a generated crystal report without using database, when previewing the report it ask for username and password to database.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without connecting to a database? Many thanks.

```
ReportDocument tempCover = new ReportDocument();
tempCover.Load(@"test.rpt");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
DataColumn FrontImage = new DataColumn("FrontImage");
DataColumn BackImage = new DataColumn("BackImage");
dt.Columns.Add(FrontImage);
dt.Columns.Add(BackImage);
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(row);
tempCover.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by passing datatable to report instead of dataset.

```
tempCover.SetDataSource(ds);
```

to

```
tempCover.SetDataSource(dt);
```